# Specific php document for a page

Tags: php

I'm Doing a site with some content that can be updated by Wordpress, but, It would be a lot times if I could write a php document for one page and other php document for another page, Like front-page.php. Is it somehow possible?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for 'page templates'.

Try out the codex:

[Page Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates)

Page templates allow you to completely change the look of separate pages on your website and still allow dynamic content to be updated by Wordpress.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering me, you are Awesome! Keep Answering Questions! Thanks a lot again! I'm still a newbie in Wordpress.